# How do you count the amount of lines from a file that is read through a byte array directly? NOT from the file itself

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arrays

I have used *OpenFileDialog* where the user opens a file and data will be displayed in the *DataGridView* Table. I have created and read the file through a byte array, and now I want to get the total line count from **THIS** - **NOT** from the actual file using *File.ReadAllLines*.

### Creating the byte array that reads the file:

```
byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

### Reading line count from a file:

```
// This is a no-no!     
int lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(path).Count();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution although different to my question as it doesn't involve an array at all. See my other question here [Adding rows to second column ONLY - populating data using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21404668/2952390) and the actual question is the answer for this one. I have used just FileInfo and DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking. You are opening a binary or ascii file? Are you trying to count the lines in the datagridview after you bind it? Try

```
int count = DataGridView.RowCount;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am opening a binary file, and not trying to count the rows in the DataGridView but in the array instead so I know how many rows to populate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function on the array :

```
array.Count(n => (char)n == '\n') + 1;
```

This code doesn't deal with empty lines. The + 1 is for the last line.

As the first method doesn't work, I suggest you to use the following :

```
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array);
var lineCount = str.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, int.MaxValue, StringSplitOptions.None).Count();
```

It's not optimized as it performs a full copy.

Comment: I’ve tried your solution, but it’s not giving me the correct result :/ For example, I opened a file with 11 lines and the total, using your solution, is 38. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I've updated the response with a new implementation, is it possible to have the sample data you used in your test ?

Comment: The updated response always displays 1, even when opening different files :/ I will yes, hang on

Comment: I need to see a source, It seems to be an encoding issue

Comment: re-check the link above, I have added a link to the file :)

Comment: The provided file contains five '\n' and one '\r', how many lines do you expect ? This file seems to only contains binary data...

Comment: Oh, and it was a snippet of code of the screenshot which should produce 11 rows. I'm slightly confused now, can it not be done? :/

Comment: As data contained in the file are not readable by a human, there are a few questions : what does this file contains ? what does a line should contain ? Does it have a sense to display it ? Why do you need to count lines ?

Comment: binary, hexbytes and BCD I think. each line contains info like date, location, record number etc. and should be displayed within 7 columns. I'm not sure what sense is :L I thought I needed to count lines in order to populate the rows in the DataGridView.